# Is there a defined result for when a number is raised to a matrix or vector power?

Tags: matrices, vectors, exponentiation

For example, if $A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$
is there a definition/result for $n^A$ where n is some number. If so, is there a similar/identical process if A is a vector?

Comment: $e^A=1+A+\dfrac {A^2}2+\dfrac{A^3}{3!}+\cdots$